# Event.java:6: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

i have a problem i have two classes
but there is something wrong i don't know why?

> Event.java:6: cannot find symbol

```
  public class Attendee {

    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String email;

    public Attendee(Attendee A){

      fName = A.fName;
      lName = A.lName;
      email =A.email;

    }

    public Attendee(String fName,String lName,String email){

      this.fName = fName;
      this.lName = lName;
      this.email =email;

    }


    }


    public class Event {

      private String name;
      private int soldTicketsNo;
      private Attendee w ; // here is the wrong 
    }
```

so can anyone help me please ? :)

ok i know what is the wrong

i'm working on Ubuntu OS
and I saved them into different folder and when i tried to save them in the same folder the code worked ! :)

Comment: Place the code for the public `Attendee` class in its own separate file, `Attendee.java`.

Comment: Are Event & Attende in the same package? If not then did you include Attendee in Event.java ?

Comment: Why you added first Attendee constructor??

Comment: @rgettman yes i did that but is still does not work :/

Comment: @Kakarot no they are in separate file

Comment: Are they in the same package ?

Comment: @Kakarot no they are not

Comment: You should fix imports

Answer (score 0):

Import the pakage in which you've `Attendee.class` into Your `Event.class`.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the "public" from Event so that your class looks like this:

```
public class Attendee {
private final String fName;
private final String lName;
private final String email;

public Attendee(Attendee A) {

    fName = A.fName;
    lName = A.lName;
    email = A.email;

}

public Attendee(String fName, String lName, String email) {

    this.fName = fName;
    this.lName = lName;
    this.email = email;

}

}

class Event {

private String name;
private int soldTicketsNo;
private Attendee w; // here is the wrong
}
```

Comment: Why does this fix it? Can you give an explanation.